# knockoutjs, How to detect css animation changes

Tags: knockout.js

I am currently working to modify a plugin. I need to detech changes of css animation. How can i do this.

```
<div id="block">Hello!</div>

<input data-bind="click:Animate" type="button" value="Animate" >
```

Viewmodel

```
function vm(){
    var self = this
    self.Width = ko.observable('70%')
    self.Width.subscribe(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })

    self.Animate = function(){
        $( "#block" ).animate({
            width: self.Width(),
        }, 1500 );            
    }
}

$('document').ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new vm())
})
```

subscribe is not called. How can i detect css animation change with observable?

### Fiddle

Comment: Why would you expect (for the code in this question) the `Width.subscribe` to fire? Nowhere in this code does anything update the observable's value.

Comment: i know this. That's why i have questioned how i can detect the changes? Is there any way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing currently updating the `Width` observable, it won't automatically track things for you like this.  You could use the `progress` option of animate to do so:

```
function vm(){
    var self = this
    self.Width = ko.observable('70%')
    self.Width.subscribe(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })

    self.Animate = function(){
        $( "#block" ).animate({
            width: self.Width(),
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            progress: function() {
                self.Width($(this).width());
            }
        });            
    }
}
```

Though this is still a bit odd, as you're then using the `Width` observable to both set the width to animate to as well as report progress.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I can use a separate observable for width and for change made. That's working fine.

Comment: Can't say I've used `progress` myself before, you may want to [check the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) for it as one of the parameters may contain the current width without having to read it back off the element.